# Gradle init repository to use for converting maven project to gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a maven project I want to convert to a gradle build. So I do this:

```
 cd project/
 gradle init 
 ...tell gradle yes i want to generate a gradle build from this and use groovy (defaults) ...
```

Then what happens is gradle tries to GET resources from 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/...' and fails spectacularly because I am behind a firewall and I need to provide the repository for it to use. And I specified a repo in `~/.gradle/build.gradle` only it is willfully ignoring it. Why? How can I get this to work ?

EDIT, script source ~/.gradle/init.gradle :

```
 allprojects {
      buildscript {
           repositories{
                mavenLocal()
                maven {
                     url 'https://my.artifactory.server.com/repo'
                     credentials {
                            username="me"
                            password="supersecret"
                     }
                }
           }
       }
  }
```

If I comment out the `maven { ... }` it will run but fails to `HTTP GET` from central (because of firewall) I need to tell it to use whatever server i put in `url`

Comment: try to declare your repo in `~/.gradle/init.gradle`  instead of `~/.gradle/build.gradle`, and it should work. see Init Scripts doc  here ; https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html#sec:using_an_init_script

Comment: Tried it , keep getting syntax error `initialization script '.../init.gradle: 1: Unexpected input: '{' @ line 1 ... repositories{` no matter what decl i try: repositories , allprojects { , etc. Same syntax error on the first curly brace, tried dos2unix back and forth, etc, cannot get it to take any type of repository declaration using an init script in `gradle init` task

Comment: I've just made quick test with init.gradle content:  `allprojects {
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
    }
 repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    } 
} `   => works fine. could you provide your complete init script? (with offuscated repo urls )

Comment: If i do it your way with `mavenCentral()` it will at least run the command, but as soon as i add my own `maven { url ... }` repository it fails with the syntax error as commented above ... i cannot connec to `mavenCentral()` i dont have a proxy for it, i have to supply my own artifactory repo url , which is what i am trying to do

Comment: It's time to see your script source.

Comment: Source is exactly what M.Ricciuti posted , i just cannot figure out why this wont work, like `gradle init` just doesn't want to accept talking to external servers and `mavenCentral() ` just will not work bc of firewall

Comment: Did you manage to figure out how to get `gradle init` to use a custom repository? I have the same problem where I need to use a different url but it uses repo.maven.apache.org everytime.

Comment: init script is wrong, put an empty init script in your `~/.gradle/init.gradle` with nothing in it, then at the top of your build.gradle define `buildscript{ ext{} repositories{ maven { ... }} dependencies{...} }` after that `apply plugin: ...` and after that `repositories{ maven {...} ... }` and after that `dependencies{...}` that should work, it will used top level `buildscript` to resolve plugins and then setup repos for your project build

Comment: At least that's what i htink i did, cant remember exactly , been a while i dont have original source code